# Confusing between "having" or "to have"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Which sentence is correct? If both are correct, do they have the same meaning?

> **A)** Being happy is *to have* dreams in life
>
> **B)** Being happy is *having* dreams in life

Comment: *In principle*, both are syntactically valid (and unquestionably there's only one possible *meaning*). But *in practice*, native speakers wouldn't normally produce #A because of the clumsy / non-idiomatic clash of verb forms. Consistency is fine either way: *Being happy is having dreams in life*, OR *To be happy is to have dreams in life*. But semantically they're both a bit "suspect" anyway, since they both effectively "equate" the two states - whereas in fact it's more accurate to say that having dreams *leads to* happiness, not that they are "the same thing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nuance of *to have* and *having* is interesting. In addition to the matter of *present* and *continuous*, this also speaks about the possession and the action.

> Being happy is to have dreams in life - *to have* here talks a bit more about the *possession.* 
>   Being happy is having dreams in life - *having* here talks a bit more about the *action*.

Though both will convey the message to me that if one wants to be happy in their life, they should have dreams.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing    - See section under "Uses" for more detail.

Both sentences are correct, though the usage is slightly different.    In English, the ending “-ing” on a verb, allows the verb to be used as a noun.  As a noun, it can also be the subject, by referring to the action or act as a “thing”.

Let's use the following example:

Drink  - noun and verb cases.

I like to drink wine on weekends.

Drinking wine is what I like to do on weekends.

(In the 2nd sentence, the act of doing something, "Drinking" is the subject.